# How to keep an unordered list centered within the screen?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, layout

I have the following unordered list within a div:

```
<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>|</li> 
        <li>About Us</li> 
        <li>|</li> 
        <li>Privacy Policy</li> 
        <li>|</li> 
        <li>Copyright</li> 
        <li>|</li> 
        <li>Contact Us</li> 
        <li>|</li> 
        <li>Press Inquiries</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want this footer text to stay centered in the screen no matter the width of the window.  How would I do this using CSS??

Comment: You cannot have text outside of <li> in an <ul>. You need <li>|</li> for your separators.

Comment: Don't have list items consisting entirely of a decorative pipe character - replace the pipe characters with CSS. (And a validator can tell you what is wrong with it - http://validator.w3.org/ )

Comment: fixed the HTML... thanks guys

Comment: Now it is valid, but nonsense.

Comment: A list is used to list related things. the pipes "|" are not the things you are listing so they should be removed. You can add separators with background images or side borders on the other li elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#footer{
   text-align:center; 
}
```

Comment: Assuming that the list items have been edited to display: inline - which the OP didn't mention.

Comment: margion: 0 auto;
width: 50%; #change to suitable value
is better

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
#footer_list {text-align:center;}
```

or

```
#footer_list {width:500px; margin:0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns/) describes, in part, how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to [center a floated list](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support) by using relative positioning too.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
li {
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
}
```