# centre unordered list of mixed text and graphics

Tags: html, css

I have a css ul list that serves as a navigation bar where the last (rightmost) element of the list varies in position relative to the containing table (of fixed width: 540px) depending on browser zoom. Is there any way to centre the whole given that the middle element is a styled image (I have attached a screenshot below to illustrate)?

[image: Sample]

The middle roll-over image was (seemingly) the only way that I could have an encrypted PayPal form in the nav bar behave as a hyperlink like all the other elements without actually using an insecure PayPal href link for order details.

My external css and related html below.

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:125%;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.hover-effect{ 
    width:93px; 
    height: 36px; 
    background-image:url("images/pp1.gif"); 
    display:block; 
    border:none; 
    color:transparent;
}

.hover-effect:hover{ 
    background-image:url("images/pp2.gif");
}


<table align="center" border="0" width="540">
<tr>
<td>

<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="information.htm">Information</a></li>
<li><a href="filling.htm">Remplissage</a></li>
<li><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input class="hover-effect" type="submit" name="submit" value="&nbsp;" style= "cursor:pointer">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7----- ... -----END PKCS7-----">

</form></li>
<li><a href="delivery.htm">Livraison</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep an unordered list centered within the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058754/how-to-keep-an-unordered-list-centered-within-the-screen)

Comment: Pete: html now added.

Answer (score 0):

Html added as requested, but no response. The suggestion that this question has already been answered is unhelpful as having gone through the 5 suggested answers, nowhere was the solution to this problem to be found. In the end, I found the solution myself: simply, 'margin-left:10px;'